# How to hide/delete action menu in a form?

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

I cannot find a way to hide or delete the action menu out of the form.

[image: action menu]

I tried:

- `<delete>` tag
- replace it
- using `ir.values`
- domain

None of them work.

This is the code of the action button from the standard xml file.

```
<record id="action_product_template_price_list_report" model="ir.actions.server">
    <field name="name">Generate Pricelist</field>
    <field name="groups_id" eval="[(4, ref('product.group_product_pricelist'))]"/>
    <field name="model_id" ref="product.model_product_template"/>
    <field name="binding_model_id" ref="product.model_product_template"/>
    <field name="state">code</field>
    <field name="code">
ctx = env.context
ctx.update({'default_pricelist': env['product.pricelist'].search([], limit=1).id})
action = {
    'name': 'Pricelist Report',
    'type': 'ir.actions.client',
    'tag': 'generate_pricelist',
    'context': ctx,
}
    </field>
</record>
```

Comment: Create one group and do not provide access to any user and apply add that group in action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what some parts of this code do, but I found it and edited it to solve my issue. The action is hidden now.

```
from odoo import api, models, tools

class IrActionsInherit(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'ir.actions.actions'

    @api.model
    @tools.ormcache('frozenset(self.env.user.groups_id.ids)', 'model_name')
    def get_bindings(self, model_name):
        result = super(IrActionsInherit, self).get_bindings(model_name)
        actions = result.get('action')
        for action in actions:
            if action.get('name') == 'Generate Pricelist':
                actions.remove(action)
                result.update({'action': actions})
        return result
```

Comment: How to get the active record id inside get_bindings ?

Answer (score 3):

There are two easy possibilities:

1. Just change it under technical settings of a server action

There is a button on the server action form view, which will create or unlink the action's menu action. The code for those two buttons can be found [here](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/f9b12a59ea618fa598f0ffb6869f027c6a39bc2d/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_actions.py#L487-L498)

```py
def create_action(self):
    """ Create a contextual action for each server action. """
    for action in self:
        action.write({'binding_model_id': action.model_id.id,
                        'binding_type': 'action'})
    return True

def unlink_action(self):
    """ Remove the contextual actions created for the server actions. """
    self.check_access_rights('write', raise_exception=True)
    self.filtered('binding_model_id').write({'binding_model_id': False})
    return True
```

I'm not sure if this works against module updates, but would be very grateful if somebody can test it and write it as comment under this answer.

As you can see the second possibility results from the first.

2. remove the `binding_model_id` from the server action

```xml
<record id="product.action_product_template_price_list_report" model="ir.actions.server">
    <field name="binding_model_id" eval="False" />
</record>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Hide print action](https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/14.0/hide_print_action/)

Hope this will work for you.